# Why do std::generate() and std::generate_n() require different iterators?

Tags: c++, iterator, language-lawyer

I was looking at [`generate()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) and [`generate_n()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) in cppreference and am trying to understand why does `generate()` require `ForwardIterator`, whereas `generate_n()` requires `OutputIterator` for the range? (I checked the latest working draft of the Standard, and it's the same requirement.)

Because, at least their possible implementations seem to require identical iterator concepts and `OutputIterator` seems to be enough:

`generate()`:

```
template<class ForwardIt, class Generator>
void generate(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, Generator g)
{
    while (first != last) {
        *first++ = g();
    }
}
```

`generate_n()`:

```
template<class OutputIt, class Size, class Generator>
OutputIt generate_n(OutputIt first, Size count, Generator g)
{
    for (Size i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        *first++ = g();
    }
    return first;
}
```

Same story with `std::fill()` and `std::fill_n()`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> at least their possible implementations seem to require identical iterator concept and `OutputIterator` seems to be enough

[OutputIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/OutputIterator) doesn't support equality / inequality comparison (including `operator!=` used in the possible implementation of `generate()` you showed) and multipass guarantee, while [ForwardIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator) does. That means `OutputIterator` can't be used for representing a range via two iterators (e.g. `[first, last)`) which is required by `generate()`'s interface.

> Equality and inequality may not be defined for output iterators. Even if an operator== is defined, x == y need not imply ++x == ++y.

Answer (score 9):

[songyuanyao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45254268/5722863) explains the matter from a technical viewpoint. I'll try to provide a bit more informal explanation.

Many STL algorithms, including `generate` and `fill`, are applied to a number of items. The way an algorithm must be able to access those items defines the requirements for the iterator.

In your case, the definition of `generate` contains:

```
...
while (first != last) {  // implies that Iter implements operator!=
  *first++;              // implies that Iter implements operator++
```

While the second requirement seems to be satisfied by any iterator type (after all, that's what iterators are all about — iterating over things :)), the support for comparison `operator!=` is provided by not all iterator types.

For instance, you cannot use `ostream_iterator` for `std::generate`. But, you can, *e.g.*, output a fixed number of generated values into a stream via `std::generate_n`.

Here's [a very artificial example at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b1260a5949d9a1a). Once I start thinking about real-life applications, I'd guess the ability to work with OutputIterators may be useful for implementing some serialization logic.

Answer (score 8):

`generate()` and `generate_n()`, like all the standard library algorithms, operate on a **range**, that is, a sequence of values accessed through an iterator. In order to apply an operation to all of the elements of a range the algorithm has to know where the range begins and where it ends. There are two common ways of giving it that information: you can specify the range with an iterator and a length, and use a loop of the form `while (length-- != 0) { ... ++first; }`; or you can specify the range with a pair of iterators `[first, last)` and use a loop of the form `while (first != last) { ... ++first; }`.

For the first version, you need to be able to increment the iterator and, for these algorithms, write a value through the iterator. Those are the main properaties of a **output iterator**, and that's all you need for `generate_n()`.

For the second version, you need to be able to increment the iterator and write a value through the iterator, just like the first version. You **also** have to be able to compare two iterators for equality, and an output iterator doesn't support that; you have to have at least a **forward iterator**. That's why `generate()`, which takes a range designated by a pair of iterators, requires a forward iterator.